# My JQuery functions are not working - What's wrong with my syntax?

Tags: jquery, function, formatting

```
jQuery.preloadImages = function() { for(var i = 0; i<arguments.length; i++) jQuery("<img>").attr("src", arguments[i]); }

$(function() {

$('#background-wrap img').css('opacity',0);
$('#background-wrap img').animate({ opacity: 1}, 3000);

});
```

It's not doing performing of the functions that are in the code. Where did I mess up the syntax because I can seem to figure it out myself?

Cheers!

Comment: Where are you calling your function?

Comment: What are you expecting it to do? The code wrapped in `$(function(){});` will execute on when the dom is loaded. Is there an element with id of "background-wrap" with img children on page load? What are you trying to do with the bit at top (`jQuery.preloadImages = ...`)? if you are trying to add a function to jQuery, try `$.fn.dropDown = function() {...`. This function doesn't appear to be called anywhere. Could you provide more of your code? HTML too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<img>
```

should be replaced with 
`img`

```
jQuery.preloadImages = function() { for(var i = 0; i<arguments.length; i++) jQuery("img").attr("src", arguments[i]); }

$(function() {

$('#background-wrap img').css('opacity',0);
$('#background-wrap img').animate({ opacity: 1}, 3000);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
jQuery('<img>')
```

Use:

```
jQuery('img')
```

Also, read [jQuery Plugin Authoring](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) for information about how to extend jQuery. In the code above `preloadImages()` is also not being called.